# Access Export Union Query Error (The query cannot be completed)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, union

I have a database that is used to create a data file for a customer. The database has two linked tables that are linked to tables that are both in another database (but within the same database as each other). Their structure is identical.

I have a union query set up to combine both linked tables.

I am using a Macro to export that query but after running for a short while I get the error "The query cannot be completed. Either the size of the query set....."

Does Access have a limitation on union query size? Combined, the tables are a lot of data but I'm confused as both the tables I'm combining are in the same database.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Actually, you didn't provide enough information in your question to answer it somehow, e.g. what your query looks like, how many records it returns, whether it works within access (without macro export), how your macro works. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It transpires that in my case I should be using Union All instead of Union as there will never be duplicates in the two tables I'm combining.

It appears that the de-duplication of the tables is what was taking up memory.